# ¿Cómo evitar el "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" generado al intentar realizar una petición GET en un entorno local?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, heroku, cors

Estoy tratando de crear una pequeña aplicación usando la API de Deezer. Básicamente, quiero obtener un json con todas las canciones que tengo en una determinada playlist para luego hacer x cosa. El problema es que, al tratar de hacerlo de manera local, con un simple `fetch` me aparece el error de la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe?answertab=trending#tab-top) ofrecen una solución, usando Heroku, pero la verdad es que no entiendo muy bien qué hacer. Cloné el respositorio y demás pero... no supe qué más hacer de ahí en adelante.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es muy simple

```js
async function getDeezerData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.deezer.com/playlist/10344346102");
  console.log(response);
}
```

También intenté haciendo básicamente lo mismo con XMLHttpRequest pero el mensaje es prácticamente el mismo.

Comment: Al parecer, deezer no responde con la cabecera Allow origin, no hay mucho que puedas hacer desde javascript en el cliente. La solución es que uses un proxy que haga el request por ti, o bien hacer el request desde un servidor, no con un navegador.

Comment: ¿Para eso no serviría la solución en Heroku que plantean en el post citado?

Comment: Claro, al parecer sugieren una forma de hacer un proxy propio.

Answer (score 1):

Esto es un problema de CORS policy. Si no sabe que es CORS puede leer un poco este sitio: https://nordicapis.com/10-free-to-use-cors-proxies/

Básicamente usted no puede desde Localhost hacer una petición a ese API, por esa razón debe hacerlo mediante un proxy o bien hacer el llamado o las pruebas publicando su sitio en un servidor web, existen algunos servidores proxy que le pueden servir para las pruebas locales pero ya cuando publique su sitio no es necesario utilizar esos servidores proxy:
Por ejemplo podría realizar el llamado usando el proxy de cors anywhere de esta forma:

https://{proxy}/{url del API}:

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.deezer.com/playlist/10344346102

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto podría intentarlo desde el javascript de esta forma:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.deezer.com/playlist/10344346102", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Nótese que es necesario el header de X-Requested-With

Comment: No tenía idea de esas cabeceras. Sí, es verdad, funcionó de esa forma pero solo después de entrar directamente al link y oprimir el botón que da acceso al uso de este servicio. ¿No habría otra forma de hacerlo? Por lo que veo en la imagen adjunta, usted no tuvo que hacer uso de él. ¿o sí?